# How to use with in Query Builder in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to fetch data using slug between 2 table,
When I am using Eloquent then everything is fine but How to convert that query in Query Builder.

Eloquent Query :

```
$results = Product::orderBy('id','desc')->with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query){
        $query->where('slug', request()->sub_category);
    })->paginate(24);
```

Here I am using two tables product and categories.

Query Builder :

```
$results = DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('wishlists', 'products.product_id', '=', 'wishlists.product_id')
        ->select('products.*', 'wishlists.wishlist_id', 'wishlists.user_id')
        ->with('menus')
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($query){
            $query->where('slug', request()->category);
        })
        ->orderBy('products.name', 'asc')
        ->paginate(24);
```

But here I am using 3 tables, Product, menu and Wishlist. Bcoz when user go to product page, I will highlight wishlisted product too.

Error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()
```

Comment: `with()` is only be work with the Eloquent model. i.e `Product::with('menu')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple with eloquent too,

try this

```
$results = Product::orderBy('id','desc')->with(['menus','categories' => function ($query){
    $query->where('slug', request()->sub_category);
}])->paginate(24);
```